# Parse, Android: retrieving data set from UserObject through Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse with Android; I am attempting to create a query that will retrieve a user by a specified type, and if that user is of that type, get data associated with that user.

The larger goal is to create a CustomList View with the data.  I have this ParseQuery:

```
//Parse data to get users
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_PRACTICE_NAME);
query.whereEqualTo("userType", "midwife");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (user == null) {
            Log.d("user", "The getFirst request failed.");
            // You don't have a good value to use, so figure
            // out a way to handle that scenario
        } else {
            Log.d("id", "Retrieved the object.");

            String midwifefirm = user.getString("practicename");
            String experience = user.getString("yearsofexperience");
            String education = user.getString("education");
            String philosophy = user.getString("practicephilosophy");
        }
    }
});
```

The error is at this point:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
```

It states:

> "Anonymous class derived from FindCallback must be declared abstract
>   or implement abstract method done(List, ParseException) in
>   Findcallback

If I change the done method to:

```
public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e)
```

The error goes away, but then, I can't seem to use getString (error: cannot resolve method).

My guess is I am getting an array list in the done method, and then trying to retrieve individual Strings of data...

How can I setup the query to get data about specific user types using the `ParseQuery`?

Thanks so much

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your query is for a list of users and `findInBackground()` returns a list therefore uses `FindCallback<ParseUser>()`. There are multiple solutions depending on what you are trying to do:

- Iterate through the list where each item would be a `ParseUser` and then you can call `getString()` on each
- Use `query.getInBackground("userObjectId", new GetCallback<ParseObject>()` which will return a single user and operate on that.
- Use `getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()` if you don't have the userObjectId but you know that your query should only return one user and then use that object.